# How to insert into SQL this object - keys + Arrays of values

Tags: javascript, postgresql, forms

I've tried all day long to insert into SQL this object with datamapper method

```
{   year: [ '2022', '2022' ],   month: [ 'mars', 'mars' ],   day: [ '15', '15' ],   logo: [ 'projection', 'mécanique' ],   title: [ 'Ciné ', 'Réparation' ],   description: [ "c'est bien", "c'est cool" ] }
```

I get this object after a form / post  method.

**dataMapper.js**

```
const query = {
                text: `INSERT INTO "events"("year", "month", "day", "logo", "title", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4,$5, $6)`,
                values: [data.year, data.month, data.day, data.logo, data.title, data.description]
            }
```

I can only insert one row of data in this form (which is normal, I guess) but I've added a button which clones my "event-card". this is where problems begin. and the number a event-card could be form only on to many...

****my html code ****

```
 <form method="POST" action="/la-roue-libre">
        <div class="events">
            <div class="event-card">

                <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Année" value="2022">
                <select name="month" placeholder="month">
                    <option value="">--Quel mois?--</option>
                    <option value="janvier">janvier</option>
                    <option value="février">février</option>
                    <option value="mars">mars</option>
                    <option value="avril">avril</option>
                    <option value="mai">mai</option>
                    <option value="juin">juin</option>
                    <option value="juillet">juillet</option>
                    <option value="aout">aout</option>
                    <option value="septembre">septembre</option>
                    <option value="octobre">octobre</option>
                    <option value="novembre">novembre</option>
                    <option value="décembre">décembre</option>

                </select>
                <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Jour de l'évènement">
                <select name="logo" placeholder="logo">
                    <option value="">--choisir type logo--</option>
                    <option value="balade">Balade</option>
                    <option value="projection">Projection</option>
                    <option value="mécanique">Mécanique</option>
                    <option value="jeux">Jeux</option>
                    <option value="musique">Musique</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titre">
                <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

                <input type="reset">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">Ajouter</div>
        <button class="publish">Publier</button>

    </form>
```

A clue would be much appreciated and sorry for my English.

loop in every ways but didn't find a solution or insert one by one but this is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the server data that is much easier to break into insertable chunks. I am assuming you're sending the data using ajax. Here's a method that cycles through multiple 'event-card' elements.

```js
document.querySelector('.publish').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  let values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.event-card').forEach(div => {
    let obj = {
      year: div.querySelector('[name=year]').value,
      day: div.querySelector('[name=day]').value,
      title: div.querySelector('[name=title]').value,
      description: div.querySelector('[name=description]').value,
    }
    values.push(obj);
  })

  console.log('ready to send to the server:', values);
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit='return false' action="/la-roue-libre">
  <div class="events">
    <div class="event-card">

      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Année" value="2022">
      <select name="month" placeholder="month">
        <option value="">--Quel mois?--</option>
        <option value="janvier">janvier</option>
        <option value="février">février</option>
        <option value="mars">mars</option>
        <option value="avril">avril</option>
        <option value="mai">mai</option>
        <option value="juin">juin</option>
        <option value="juillet">juillet</option>
        <option value="aout">aout</option>
        <option value="septembre">septembre</option>
        <option value="octobre">octobre</option>
        <option value="novembre">novembre</option>
        <option value="décembre">décembre</option>

      </select>
      <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Jour de l'évènement">
      <select name="logo" placeholder="logo">
        <option value="">--choisir type logo--</option>
        <option value="balade">Balade</option>
        <option value="projection">Projection</option>
        <option value="mécanique">Mécanique</option>
        <option value="jeux">Jeux</option>
        <option value="musique">Musique</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titre">
      <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

      <input type="reset">
    </div>

    <div class="event-card">

      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Année" value="2022">
      <select name="month" placeholder="month">
        <option value="">--Quel mois?--</option>
        <option value="janvier">janvier</option>
        <option value="février">février</option>
        <option value="mars">mars</option>
        <option value="avril">avril</option>
        <option value="mai">mai</option>
        <option value="juin">juin</option>
        <option value="juillet">juillet</option>
        <option value="aout">aout</option>
        <option value="septembre">septembre</option>
        <option value="octobre">octobre</option>
        <option value="novembre">novembre</option>
        <option value="décembre">décembre</option>

      </select>
      <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Jour de l'évènement">
      <select name="logo" placeholder="logo">
        <option value="">--choisir type logo--</option>
        <option value="balade">Balade</option>
        <option value="projection">Projection</option>
        <option value="mécanique">Mécanique</option>
        <option value="jeux">Jeux</option>
        <option value="musique">Musique</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titre">
      <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

      <input type="reset">
    </div>

    <div class="event-card">

      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Année" value="2022">
      <select name="month" placeholder="month">
        <option value="">--Quel mois?--</option>
        <option value="janvier">janvier</option>
        <option value="février">février</option>
        <option value="mars">mars</option>
        <option value="avril">avril</option>
        <option value="mai">mai</option>
        <option value="juin">juin</option>
        <option value="juillet">juillet</option>
        <option value="aout">aout</option>
        <option value="septembre">septembre</option>
        <option value="octobre">octobre</option>
        <option value="novembre">novembre</option>
        <option value="décembre">décembre</option>

      </select>
      <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Jour de l'évènement">
      <select name="logo" placeholder="logo">
        <option value="">--choisir type logo--</option>
        <option value="balade">Balade</option>
        <option value="projection">Projection</option>
        <option value="mécanique">Mécanique</option>
        <option value="jeux">Jeux</option>
        <option value="musique">Musique</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titre">
      <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

      <input type="reset">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">Ajouter</div>
  <button class="publish">Publier</button>

</form>
```